# How can I get the length of each option in a dropdown list of HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this javascript function to verify the length of a phone number of a select dropdown list of HTML.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function test(){

    var max_length_internet_number = 10;
    var max_length_mobilephone_number = 11;
    var total_length = 15;

    var length_telephone_prefix = document.getElementById('prefix').options.length;

    var telephone_textbox = document.getElementById('phone');
    var message = "";


    //MIGHT BE... - THIS IS ONLY A TEST

    if(length_telephone_prefix + telephone_textbox.value.length == total_length && telephone_textbox.value.length > max_length_mobilephone_number){

     message.setCustomValidity("ERROR, The length of a number of a mobile phone don't be greater than 15 digits");
     return false;
    }else{

    message.setCustomValidity('');
    return true;
    }


}
</script>
```

I think that the line that says: `document.getElementById('prefix').options.length` certainly will take the length of the option of the dropdown list that I have, but really? I think that this line will take **all** not each option depending on the option was selected.

This is the drop down list and the textbox.

```
<select id="prefix">
  <option name="mobile" value="+234">+234</option>
  <option name="internet" value="+4388">+4388</option>
  <option name="others" value="">Other number</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" maxlength="15"/>
```

Is possible to take the length of each `<option></option>` depending on what option was selected, using javascript, maybe taking his name or id of each option in different variables. And then call the function in the input.

Comment: what do you want to achieve here? want to get length of selected option only?

Comment: `document.getElementById('prefix').options.length` will yield 3 which is the total number of `<option>`  `select#prefix` has.

Comment: @ArunKumar. Yes. I want to take only the length of each option, depending on the selection was made. if was selected the mobile option, the length would be 4 characters, and successively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take the length of the selected dropdown option then you can try this:

```
var list = document.getElementById('prefix');
var selected_option_length = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value.length;
console.log(selected_option_length);
```